# Can I play Red Dead Redemption 2 without an internet connection?

Tags: ps4, red-dead-redemption-2

Can I play Red Dead Redemption 2 with no internet? I want to play Red Dead 2 on Play Station 4. Do I need to use the internet to set up the PS4 and play the game?

Answer (score 5):

You will be able to play Red Dead 2's single player story offline, but not Red Dead online without a connection. As long as you buy a physical copy of the game, all you need to do to set it up is to install it from the disk. Typically, the game would install as you play it, but this game comes on 2 separate disks. This is why you need to install first, and play when finished.

Comment: Don't forget that there was a huge day 1 patch as well.  Internet would be needed to update to the latest version.

Comment: @Stephen If you don't have a connection the game won't even know it's out of date I'd imagine, and surely you could still play?

Comment: very true but the day 1 patch fixed some pretty major bugs.  While I'm sure Rockstar Games wouldn't release anything that crashed every 5 minutes, there could still be game breaking bugs in the disc version, hence the need for a 3GB day one patch.

Comment: As a matter of fact the game is playable without an internet connection and even if you had one and it were to be an "outdated" version you can still play, even while it downloads the update or simply you can decide not to ever update it at all.

Answer (score -2):

No internet = No play.  Even in story mode. Rockstar's Social Club has to launch the game (and with Steamworks).  As for sticking with an older unpatched copy, I have no idea.

Comment: Im gonna say the same thing I said on SEXICATOR's answer... There is no Rockstar Launcher (that Im aware of) for the PS4 edition.

Answer (score -3):

No, you can't play offline because you have to start the game from Rockstar launcher which requires the purchase of the game.

Comment: Correct me if Im wrong.. but why would the PS4 need to go through the Rockstar launcher? Are you sure you arent confused and think the OP was talking about the PC version?